# Azure data factory - Voluminous copy activity - dataware

Tags: performance, copy, azure-data-factory

I'm currently facing to a datafactory problem and can't managed to find a solution:
I've mad a pipeline with a copy activity which send data from a datawarehouse to an oracle database.

The pipeline run fine, but take a lot of time (4h-5h).
I think it's caused by the amount of data (Approximately 12 millions rows)

Do you have any idea for making this pipelin run faster?

Thanks for your help,

Guif

Answer (score 1):

Try bigger DIU (old name: DMU) and increase the parallelism in the copy activity.

You may also try stage the data into a blob first then followed by a copy to Oracle. I know SQL to SQL would have better performance with staging.

Be sure to use an IR region that is close to your data sources.